# Variable in another module to be used in current module

Tags: module, lua, coronasdk

Here it goes my code

```
ModuleName.FunctionName.VariableName
```

I'm wondering if this is applicable, we all know that to load a a function in another module you have to use this code:

```
ModuleName.FunctionName
```

I was wondering If my given code is applicable.

Answer (score 5):

You can use variables in another module, but the syntax is not like `ModuleName.FunctionName.VariableName` because functions have no fields.

As an example, consider this simple module `foo.lua`:

```
local M = {}

function M.func()
    print("calling func")
end

M.var = 42

return M
```

Note that similar to `func()`, the variable `var` must be global, or it's private to the module.

You can use the variable `var` similar to the way to use the function `func()`:

```
local foo = require "foo"

foo.func()

print(foo.var)
```

Output:

```
calling func
42
```

Answer (score 2):

There is two ways you can achieve this.
**1 :**

```
-- message.lua
local M = {}
function M.message()
    print("Hello")
end
return M
```

You can call above module into other file.

```
-- test.lua
local msg = require "message"
msg.message()
```

**2  :**

```
--message.lua    
msg = "message"
```

You can call above module by  `dofile`

```
-- test.lua 
dofile ("/home/django/lua/message.lua")    -- you should provide complete path of message.lua
print(msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions don't have fields, but tables do. So you can do

```
ModuleName.FunctionName  -- a function in ModuleName 
ModuleName.VariableName  -- a variable in ModuleName
ModuleName.TableName.FieldName -- a field from a TableName which is in ModuleName
```

Note `FieldName` could itself reference a table, and `VariableName` could be a function, table, string, number, coroutine, etc.